# php search text file for any wav file names

Tags: php, regex, search

I have a series of files which contain raw text or json data, in these files will be wav file names. All of the wav file have the suffix of `.wav`

Is there anyway using php I can search an individual text or json file and return an array of of any `.wav` files found ?

This example of random text contains 6 .wav files, how would I search this and extract the filenames ?

```
Spoke as as other again ye. Hard on to roof he drew. So sell side newfile.wav ye in mr evil. Longer waited mr of nature seemed. Improving knowledge incommode objection me ye is prevailed playme.wav principle in. Impossible alteration devonshire to is interested stimulated dissimilar. To matter esteem polite do if. 

Spot of come to ever test.wav hand as lady meet on. Delicate contempt received two yet advanced. Gentleman as belonging he commanded believing dejection in by. On no am winding chicken so behaved. Its preserved sex enjoyment new way behaviour. Him yet devonshire celebrated welcome.wav especially. Unfeeling one provision are smallness resembled repulsive. 

Raising say express had chiefly detract demands she. Quiet led own cause three him. Front no party young abode state up. Saved he do fruit woody of to. Met defective are allowance two perceived listening consulted contained. It chicken oh colonel pressed excited suppose to shortly. He improve started no we manners another.wav however effects. Prospect humoured mistress to by proposal marianne attended. Simplicity the far admiration preference everything. Up help home head spot an he room in. 

Talent she for lively eat led sister. Entrance strongly packages she out rendered get quitting denoting led. Dwelling confined improved it he no doubtful raptures. Several carried through an of up attempt gravity. Situation to be at offending elsewhere distrusts if. Particular use for considered projection cultivated. Worth of do doubt shall it their. Extensive existence up me last.wav contained he pronounce do. Excellence inquietude assistance precaution any impression man sufficient.
```

I've tries this, but I get no results.

```
$lines = file('test.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

    $line = trim($line);

    if (strpos($line, '*.wav') !== false) {
        echo ($line);
    }

}
```

The above text should return :

```
newfile.wav
playme.wav
test.wav
welcome.wav
another.wav
last.wav
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

Using the following:

```
$text = file_get_contents('test.txt');
preg_match_all('/\w+\.wav/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

results in an array of :

```
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(11) "newfile.wav"
        [1]=>
        string(10) "playme.wav"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "test.wav"
        [3]=>
        string(11) "welcome.wav"
        [4]=>
        string(11) "another.wav"
        [5]=>
        string(8) "last.wav"
      }
}
```

So an array of the wav files with in an array, how do I get just the array of wav files ? Thanks

This does't work correctly for wav files with spaces in there names.
any ideas ?

Comment: change `if (strpos($line, '*.wav')` to `if(strpos($line, '.wav')`

Comment: Also you are printing the entire line?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all('~\S+\.wav\b~', $text, $matches)`, you may see the result if you `print_r($matches[0])`. You need to read the file in as a single string though for it to work, use `$text = file_get_contents('test.txt');`.

Answer (score 2):

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/UGzly2/1) might help you to design an expression as you wish and test it, maybe something similar to:

```
([a-z]+\.wav)
```

You can also add more boundaries to it, if you might want to.

[image: enter image [![description] here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMec7.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMec7.png)

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

#### PHP Code

You could also use `preg_match_all` to do so, maybe something similar to:

```
$re = '/([a-z]+\.wav)/m';
$str = 'Spoke as as other again ye. Hard on to roof he drew. So sell side newfile.wav ye in mr evil. Longer waited mr of nature seemed. Improving knowledge incommode objection me ye is prevailed playme.wav principle in. Impossible alteration devonshire to is interested stimulated dissimilar. To matter esteem polite do if.

    Spot of come to ever test.wav hand as lady meet on. Delicate contempt received two yet advanced. Gentleman as belonging he commanded believing dejection in by. On no am winding chicken so behaved. Its preserved sex enjoyment new way behaviour. Him yet devonshire celebrated welcome.wav especially. Unfeeling one provision are smallness resembled repulsive.

    Raising say express had chiefly detract demands she. Quiet led own cause three him. Front no party young abode state up. Saved he do fruit woody of to. Met defective are allowance two perceived listening consulted contained. It chicken oh colonel pressed excited suppose to shortly. He improve started no we manners another.wav however effects. Prospect humoured mistress to by proposal marianne attended. Simplicity the far admiration preference everything. Up help home head spot an he room in.

    Talent she for lively eat led sister. Entrance strongly packages she out rendered get quitting denoting led. Dwelling confined improved it he no doubtful raptures. Several carried through an of up attempt gravity. Situation to be at offending elsewhere distrusts if. Particular use for considered projection cultivated. Worth of do doubt shall it their. Extensive existence up me last.wav contained he pronounce do. Excellence inquietude assistance precaution any impression man sufficient. ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Test Script for RegEx

```js
const regex = /([a-z]+\.wav)/gm;
const str = `Spoke as as other again ye. Hard on to roof he drew. So sell side newfile.wav ye in mr evil. Longer waited mr of nature seemed. Improving knowledge incommode objection me ye is prevailed playme.wav principle in. Impossible alteration devonshire to is interested stimulated dissimilar. To matter esteem polite do if.
    
    Spot of come to ever test.wav hand as lady meet on. Delicate contempt received two yet advanced. Gentleman as belonging he commanded believing dejection in by. On no am winding chicken so behaved. Its preserved sex enjoyment new way behaviour. Him yet devonshire celebrated welcome.wav especially. Unfeeling one provision are smallness resembled repulsive.
    
    Raising say express had chiefly detract demands she. Quiet led own cause three him. Front no party young abode state up. Saved he do fruit woody of to. Met defective are allowance two perceived listening consulted contained. It chicken oh colonel pressed excited suppose to shortly. He improve started no we manners another.wav however effects. Prospect humoured mistress to by proposal marianne attended. Simplicity the far admiration preference everything. Up help home head spot an he room in.
    
    Talent she for lively eat led sister. Entrance strongly packages she out rendered get quitting denoting led. Dwelling confined improved it he no doubtful raptures. Several carried through an of up attempt gravity. Situation to be at offending elsewhere distrusts if. Particular use for considered projection cultivated. Worth of do doubt shall it their. Extensive existence up me last.wav contained he pronounce do. Excellence inquietude assistance precaution any impression man sufficient. `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.. and I can't see why

Comment: I've still not got this working.. how would it handle files with spaces in the name ?

Answer (score 1):

#### This is why [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) were invented.

```
$text = file_get_contents('test.txt');
preg_match_all('/(\w+\.wav)/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Some good resources:

- [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) allows you to test expressions realtime

output:

```
    array(6) {
      [0] => string(11) "newfile.wav"
      [1] => string(10) "playme.wav"
      [2] => string(8) "test.wav"
      [3] => string(11) "welcome.wav"
      [4] => string(11) "another.wav"
      [5] => string(8) "last.wav"
    }
```

Comment: Should probably use preg_match_all.

Comment: Why the down vote on this ? it seems to work, I'm curious if it would cause issues ?

Comment: This does work, but provides the array of files within an array.. how do I return just the array of files ?

Comment: @Rocket Use $matches[0] as the result if you don't need the positions.

Comment: @PeterRakmanyi thanks this works well, except if the wav file has spaces in it's name. Any way to handle that ?

Comment: @Rocket If you include space characters in the matching pattern `([ \w]+\.wav)` (note the space inside the [ ]), it will match all words in the text leading up to '.wav', starting from last character not included in the pattern. So anything other than `a-z, 0-9, space`. i.e: first match will become ` So sell side newfile.wav` and so on. **Do you have any real examples of what you want to match? Please post** How would a person reading the text know what is or isn't part of the filenames? If there is a logical pattern or combination of patterns, than those can be written as regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You can explode the `$line` in terms of spaces. Now, you go through each word and check if ends with a `.wav` extension. If yes, you print the word.

```
<?php

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    $words = explode(" ",$line);
    foreach($words as $each_word){
        $wav_index = strpos($each_word, '.wav');
        if ($wav_index !== false && $wav_index === strlen($each_word) - 4) { // strict check to make sure string ends with a .wav and not being elsewhere
            echo $each_word,PHP_EOL;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Does exploding the line at spaces, then searching that add any extra load ?

Comment: @Tom It could take some extra memory, but it's negligible.

Comment: @vivek_23 the issue I have is the wav files may have spaces in there names. Any way to handle that ?

Comment: @Rocket can you let me know how are you getting these data?